# A club consists of $6$ men and $5$ women.?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways can a president and a vice-president be chosen if they cannot be both men or both women?

Comment: Choose one man and one woman, then select which of them will be president.

Comment: Hint: How many ways can you choose a male president and a female vice-president?

Comment: There are 6 ways to pick a man and 5 ways to pick a woman. Then there is one more choice: whom of them gets which post.

Answer (score 1):

Total number of ways $$=\dbinom61 \times \dbinom51 \times 2!$$ $$=60~\text{ways}$$

Answer (score 1):

The obvious alternative is simply to work through the two cases and add:

$$\underset{\text{Pres}}{\binom 51}\underset{\text{VP}}{\binom 61} + \underset{\text{Pres}}{\binom 61}\underset{\text{VP}}{\binom 51} = 5\cdot 6 + 6\cdot5 = 30+30=60$$

*Note $\binom xy$ ("$x$ choose $y$") are [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).*

Comment: same thinking. +1